# how to solve id in route and controller in laravel localization

Tags: laravel

**I get the error:**

Missing required parameter for [Route: postDetails] [URI: {language}/cars/{id}] [Missing parameter: id]."

**My Routes:**

```
Route::prefix('{language}')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/',[HomeController::class,'homePage'])->name('home');
    Route::get('cars',[AllPostsController::class,'allPosts'])->name('allPosts');
    Route::get('cars/{id}',[AllPostsController::class,'details'])->name('postDetails');
});
```

**My Middleware:**

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        \App::setLocale($request->language);
        return $next($request);
    }
```

**My Controller:**

```
public function details($language,$id){
        $post = Car::find($id);
        if($post) {
            $license_no = $post->license_no;
            if ($license_no) {
                $prefix = substr($license_no, 0, 4);
            $suffix = str_repeat('*', strlen($license_no) - 4);
                $short_license_no = $prefix . $suffix;
                $post->short_license_no = $short_license_no;
            }

            $data = Car::select('m.name as manufacturer_name','mo.name as model_name')
                    ->leftJoin('manufacturers as m','m.id','cars.manufacturer_id')
                    ->leftJoin('models as mo','mo.id','cars.model_id')
                    ->where('cars.id',$id)
                    ->first();
            return view('public.carDetail',compact('post','data','language'));
        }else {
            abort(404);
        }

    }
```

---

**My Link:**

```
<a href="{{ route('postDetails', ['language' => app()->getLocale(), 'id' => $post->id]) }}" class="stretched-link"></a>
```

Comment: Are you getting valid id from `$post->id` in href ?

Comment: Yes,I get valid id.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not passing `null` in your `id` param at link. debug it using `dd($post->id);` before your anchor tag(link). Probably `$post` is getting as null. Apart from that everything looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try edit
prefix('{language'}) ->
group(['prefix' => '{language}'])

It will work fine